# Google AdMob does not show ads

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, google-ads-api

I'm trying to put advertisements on my app, I put my app on amazon app store and then approved by google admob I set up Ad Unit ID (next level promotion) and put in both the xml and java part the appropriate code for it to work however I still don't get any Ad bar on the home of my app. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't come up?

Java:

```
   ` MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {});
    // Create an AdView and set the ad unit ID and ad size
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("*******"); 
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    // Add the AdView to your layout
    LinearLayout adContainer = findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
    if (adContainer != null) {
        adContainer.addView(adView);

        // Load an ad
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }`
```

XML:

```
       `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="***" />`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, I would recommend to follow the [official guidelines](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) to implement banner ads properly in your Android app.

**Second**, there could be various reasons for not getting ads, for example a recently created AdMob account or a newly created ad unit ID can cause problems.

**Third**, in your code, you implemented banner ads incorrectly. AdMob recommends that you **set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same way (eg set in XML or both programmatically), but not both**. When you set `app:adSize` and `app:adSize` in xml, there is no need to set the same properties programmatically.

**Fourth**, In xml you set the id of `AdView` as `android:id="@+id/ad_container"`. But in code you are accessing `AdView` as `LinearLayout` like below:

```
LinearLayout adContainer = findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
adContainer.addView(adView);
```

And you are attaching the newly created `AdView` to an another `AdView`.

**So what is the next step?**

I am assuming your activity is `MainActivity`. Then change your  code of implementation as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        //We will use R.id.ad_container here as per your XML
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

The above example is copied from [Admob Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner).

**AND** please don't use real ads for debugging, you should use Admob's [Demo AdUnit Ids](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units) to avoid policy issues.

That's all I know. Hope it will help.